# Object identity of listeners

Tags: android, scala

I have the following scenario in an Android app:

```
object Listeners {
     private var listeners = Set.empty[() => Unit]

     def register(listener: () => Unit) {
          listeners = listener + listener
     }

     def unregister(listener: () => Unit) {
          listeners = listener - listener
     }
}

class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private def myListener() { System.out.prinntln("Called") }        

    override def onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Listeners.register(myListener)
    }

    override def onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Listeners.unregister(myListener)
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though the instance of MyActivity is the same, the object passed as an argument to unregister() is different that the one received in the register() call.  I know this thanks to a debugger.

I have tried this other alternative with the same result:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private val myListener: () => { System.out.prinntln("Called") }        

    override def onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Listeners.register(myListener)
    }

    override def onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Listeners.unregister(myListener)
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is happening.
In Java, I've made many things like this, and it has always been working ok.

Update: solved small typos.

Comment: What if you define `Listener` [like this](https://gist.github.com/rightfold/bb415efc996753129b2e)?

Comment: Besides, relying on object identity like this would never pass my code review. Consider returning a handle (which can just wrap an integer) from `register` that can be passed to `unregister`, and using a map instead of a set.

Comment: Maybe it's not the most elegant way, but in Java it works and it's a very simple solution.

Comment: Defining listeners in Java this way is a standard practice: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/Removinglistenersremovetheregisteredlisteners.htm

Comment: Don't do it like that. Rather have `register` return a `Registration` object and move `unregister` to that. Not only can't you unregister something that's never been registered, more importantly your problem goes away.

Comment: nilskp: that approach is more flexible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eta-expansion doesn't give you identical functions when invoked twice. Also as you may have noticed, `Set[=> Unit]` is not an accepted type, so you better implement `Set[() => Unit]`.

I would solve this by requiring an opaque handle or identifier for the listeners. For example:

```
trait Listeners {
  type Id

  def register(listener: => Unit): Id

  def unregister(listener: Id): Unit
}

object Impl extends Listeners {  
  type Id = Function0[Unit]

  private var listeners = Set.empty[Id]

  def register(listener: => Unit): Id = {
    val fun = () => listener
    listeners += fun
    fun
  }

  def fire(): Unit = listeners.foreach(_.apply())

  def unregister(listener: Id): Unit =
    listeners -= listener
}

val x = Impl.register { println("Foo") }
Impl.fire()  // "Foo"
Impl.unregister(x)
Impl.fire()  // nada
```

Comment: I meant () => Unit.  My listeners had originally parameters and when I removed them, I deleted erroneouslly the parentheses also.  Corrected!

Comment: More info about eta-expansion: http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/

Comment: Before reading your answer, I have thought about creating an ID, but your way of creating one is really simple.